# Only run AppVeyor build on certain conditions

Tags: appveyor

I have a project on AppVeyor that I want to build in two (or three) different scenarios:

- Anytime it's on the master branch no matter which files changed, but not a pull request
- If it is a pull request on the master branch when certain files have changed
- (Maybe if it's on a different branch when certain files have changed)

Is there a way to configure appveyor.yml to do this? I'm aware of how to use APPVEYOR_PULL_REQUEST_NUMBER in one-liners, but I want to be able to apply it to the entire appveyor.yml, and combine it with the only_commits: options.

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 projects on AppVeyor connected to the same GitHub repo:

- For the **first** project got to GitHub repo settings, find Webhook connected to this project and uncheck `pull request`
- For the **second** project set `only_commits` for those certain files according to [commit filtering doc](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/how-to/filtering-commits/#commit-files-github-and-bitbucket-only)
- *Optionally*, for the **first** project set `skip_commits` for the same files according the same [commit filtering doc](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/how-to/filtering-commits/#commit-files-github-and-bitbucket-only), to eliminate duplicate builds.